# woocommerce checkout get selected shipping field dropdown value for shipping cost

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, checkout

I added a custom dropdown to checkout. Now I want to calculate shipping cost based on dropdown selected value. I think below code will be work but I don't know how to get dropdown value like cart weight.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_rate_cost', 'update_shipping_rate', 10, 2 );
function update_shipping_rate ($cost, $method) {
  global $woocommerce;

$choosen_zone = //please help me to get value of shipping_state filed


                if ( $choosen_zone == '1' )
                    $cost = 60;
                elseif ( $choosen_zone == '2' )
                    $cost = 100;
                elseif ( $choosen_zone == '3' )
                    $cost = 150;


    return $cost;

}
```